# Is there any terraform code or ARM Template code available for creating alerts in azure monitor which uses logic app as an action

Tags: terraform, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template, azure-monitoring, alerts

In our project we need to create alert rule which will trigger logic app when pipeline fails in data factory

I am able to create alerts rule with the action type "Logic App" which will trigger logic app.

now i need to automate the creation of alerts rules with the logic app as an action using code,
Is there any Terraform code or ARM Template available to create alert rule with the logic app action.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with below terraform code & I am able to create alert rule which uses logic app as a action.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "" ##name of the resource group
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "to_monitor" {
  name                = "" ## data factory Name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "main" {
  name                = "" ## Name of the action group 
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  short_name          = "" ## Short Name for the action group

    logic_app_receiver {
    name                    = "" ##logic app action name 
    resource_id             = "" ## resource id of the logic app
    callback_url            = "" ##call back url of the logic app
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }
    email_receiver {
    name                    = "" ##name of the email reciepient
    email_address           = "" #mail address of the reciepient 
    use_common_alert_schema = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "example" {
  name                = "" ## Name for the alert
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  scopes              = [azurerm_data_factory.to_monitor.id]
  description         = "Action will be triggered when Transactions count is greater than 0."

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Datafactory/factories"
    metric_name      = "PipelineFailedRuns"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 0

    dimension {
      name     = "FailureType"
      operator = "Include"
      values   = ["*"]
    }
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.main.id
  }
}
```

Here is the output of the above code for your reference

[image]